# How do I deal with special characters in vb.net?

Tags: regex, character-encoding, character

special character set: `~!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]\|:;""'<>,.?/

Is this the right way to search for items within that special character set?

```
    Regex.IsMatch(Result.Text, "^[`-/]")
```

I always get an error.... Do I need to use ASCII codes? If so, how can I do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions have a different escape syntax and rules than VB.NET. Since you're dealing with a regex string in your code, you have to make sure the string is escaped properly for regex and VB.NET.

In your example, the - needs to be escaped with a ...

```
Regex.IsMatch(Result.Text, "^[`\-/]")
```

To match any character in the provided string, try this...

```
Regex.IsMatch(Result.Text, "[`~!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\-\+=\{\}\[\]\\\|:;""'<>,\.\?/]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[`~!@#$%^&*()_+={}\[\]\\|:;""'<>,.?/-]
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/aU3wO9

In a char set, only some of them need to be escaped. like `]` and `\` and if `-` is at the end it doesn't need to be escaped.  I'm not sure about `[` so I just escaped it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an escape character in the string where there is a special character

```
Dim str() As Byte
Dim j, n As Long
Dim ContainsSpecialChar As Boolean
Dim TempVendorName As String
str = Trim(VendorName)
n = 1

For j = 0 To UBound(str) - 1 Step 2
    If (str(j) > 32 And str(j) < 47) Or (str(j) > 57 And str(j) < 65) Or (str(j) > 90 And str(j) < 97) Or (str(j) > 122) Then
         ContainsSpecialChar = True
         TempVendorName = Left(VendorName, n - 1) + "\" + Mid(VendorName, n)
         n = n + 1
    End If
    n = n + 1
Next
```